# Trouble formatting date with ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am working with Ampscript and trying to format a date in Exact Target.

I need to pull in the date out of a date/time stamp field. 
If I use

```
set @eventStartDay = Format(@eventStartDay,"dd")
```

the date pulls in with the leading zero **"05"**.

I changed it to

```
set @eventStartDay = Format(@eventStartDay,"d"),
```

hoping to drop the zero and pull in **"5"**. Instead, the entire date pulls in, formatted like this: **"2/5/2015"**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ET uses the standard C# date formatting library, so "d" will be interpreted to mean "standard short date."  (See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)).  The way around is to use a space, or a percent, which signifies a custom date format string (found at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)).  You would do something like:

```
set @eventStartDay = Format(@eventStartDay, "'{0:%d}'")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This worked:                                                                                  set @eventStartDay = Format(@eventStartDay, "%d")